# Python словарь, как проверить соответствие значения ключу

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть модуль, который рандомно выбирает ключ из словаря. Пользователь должен ввести значение этого ключа. Подскажите, как корректно написать проверку.

```
import random

example = {('one'):'один', ('two'):'два', ('three'):'три'}

get_key = random.choice(list(example))

user_in = input(f'Enter a match of {get_key} : ')

if get_key[key] in example == user_in[value]:
    print('yes')
else:
    print('Not')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if example[get_key] == user_in:
```

Comment: спасибо, то что нужно!

Answer (score 0):

У вас ошибка в `input()`.

```
import random

example = {('one'):'один', ('two'):'два', ('three'):'три'}

get_key = random.choice(list(example))

user_in = input('Enter a match of a key {}'.format(get_key))

if user_in == example.get(get_key):
    print('yes')
else:
    print('not')
```

Comment: нет, это не ошибка, так тоже можно выводить f строки

Comment: @Vadim ну значит это только у меня компилятору не понравилось